# intersection of two cubes in 3d space

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

How do I understand that a cube intersects with another cube, or is inside it?

```
let firstCube = {
  a: {
    //-15 71 -34 (position first XYZ)
    x: -15,
    y: 71,
    z: -34
  },
  b: {
    //-19 72 -38 (position second XYZ)
    x: -19,
    y: 72,
    z: -38
  }
}

let secondCube = {
  a: {
    //-16 71 -38 (position first XYZ)
    x: -16
    y:  71
    z:  -38
  },
  b: {
    //-13 71 -41 (position second XYZ)
    x: -13
    y: 71
    z: -41
  }
}

/*code*/
//idk
/*----*/
```

I could resort to a system of taking each coordinate from a cube and testing it on another cube. But I need a system that will require a minimum load on the computer, since there are a lot of objects.

Closer to the point, I’m making a server for my project on node.js, that is, 3D mini games, but the following problem arose.

Even closer to the point, I make regions as protective zones so that unnecessary entities or objects do not get there.

I tried to do this a long time ago using regular JS and I only managed to create a positioned protection system, but I couldn’t use intersections to get entities.

A little later I did it again, but only in node.js and it also worked, but I encountered another set of problems, including intersections again.

Comment: This is the english version of stackoverflow. You can use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ which is the russian version. Or you can post the translated question yourself.

Comment: What do the values in the code snippet mean?

Comment: has your cube a size?

Comment: @NinaScholz cubes size is from vectorXYZ (a) to vectorXYZ(b)

Comment: @jabaa size of cubes from vector to vector. positions for all vectors in 3d space

Comment: Are the cubes aligned to the grid or can they be rotated?

Comment: @Konrad Yes, cant be rotated

Comment: If the cubes are aligned to the grid, you only have to check the vertexes.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the cubes' edges are parallel to the x, y and z axes. (Otherwise the cubes could not be defined by two corners `a` and `b` alone.)

You should "normalize" the representation of your cubes such that `a` is the bottom left back corner (with minimal xyz coordinates) and `b` the top right front corner (with maximal xyz coordinates):

```js
function normalizedCube(cube) {
  const normalized = {a: {}, b: {}};
  if (cube.a.x < cube.b.x) {
    normalized.a.x = cube.a.x;
    normalized.b.x = cube.b.x;
  } else {
    normalized.a.x = cube.b.x;
    normalized.b.x = cube.a.x;
  }
  if (cube.a.y < cube.b.y) {
    normalized.a.y = cube.a.y;
    normalized.b.y = cube.b.y;
  } else {
    normalized.a.y = cube.b.y;
    normalized.b.y = cube.a.y;
  }
  if (cube.a.z < cube.b.z) {
    normalized.a.z = cube.a.z;
    normalized.b.z = cube.b.z;
  } else {
    normalized.a.z = cube.b.z;
    normalized.b.z = cube.a.z;
  }
  return normalized;
}
let normalizedFirstCube = normalizedCube(firstCube);
let normalizedSecondCube = normalizedCube(secondCube);
```

Then your cubes intersect if

```
normalizedFirstCube.a.x <= normalizedSecondCube.b.x &&
normalizedFirstCube.b.x >= normalizedSecondCube.a.x &&
normalizedFirstCube.a.y <= normalizedSecondCube.b.y &&
normalizedFirstCube.b.y >= normalizedSecondCube.a.y &&
normalizedFirstCube.a.z <= normalizedSecondCube.b.z &&
normalizedFirstCube.b.z >= normalizedSecondCube.a.z
```

and the second cube is inside the first if

```
normalizedFirstCube.a.x <= normalizedSecondCube.a.x &&
normalizedFirstCube.b.x >= normalizedSecondCube.b.x &&
normalizedFirstCube.a.y <= normalizedSecondCube.a.y &&
normalizedFirstCube.b.y >= normalizedSecondCube.b.y &&
normalizedFirstCube.a.z <= normalizedSecondCube.a.z &&
normalizedFirstCube.b.z >= normalizedSecondCube.b.z
```

Comment: I need to understand whether a cube is inside another cube at least a little, and not completely inside it. On the vectors in the question, I indicated 2 cubes that intersect by 1 pixel.

Comment: Inside a little is the same as intersection.